# Retrieving the last 7 days with RethinkDB during()

Tags: php, rethinkdb

I have been trying for some hours now to try and return all results in the last 7 days, using RethinkDB and PHP.

Surveying the documentation at https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/dates-and-times/javascript/ I have found the most appropriate RethinkDB function would be `during()`.

Below is my code that I have come to the realization that this task is far harder than it appears. I have attempted to use the `DateTime` from PHP directly into the `during`, but this was also not successful.

```
$sevenago = new DateTime('7 days ago');
$sevenago->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$sevenago = date_format($sevenago, 'U');
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$now = date_format($now, 'U');

$ordersLastWeek = r\table("orders")->filter(function($doc) {
    return $doc('status')->eq('shipped')
    ->rAnd($doc('time')->during(r\epochTime($sevenago), r\epochTime($now)));
})->run($conn);
```

The `time` field is stored as follows (standard RethinkDB DateTime type):

```
{"$reql_type$":"TIME","epoch_time":1509557927.661,"timezone":"+00:00"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ordersLastWeek = r\table("orders")->filter(function($doc) use ($sevenago, $now) {
    return $doc('status')->eq('shipped')->rAnd($doc('time')->during(r\epochTime($sevenago), r\epochTime($now)));
})->run($conn);
```

In your code you forgot to use `use ($sevenago, $now)` for the filter function.

Comment: Wow. Too late at night it is. Very good, you're right, I did forget to set those variables. We can also disregard the `epochTime` as we can use the `DateTime` from PHP directly now - http://codepad.org/QiTnImyo

Answer (score 0):

```
$ordersLastWeek = r\table("orders")->filter(function($doc) {
    return $doc('status')->eq('shipped')
    ->rAnd(($doc('time') > r\epoch_time($sevenago)));
})->run($conn);
```

Have you tried this. Hope it works.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I tried it with `r\epochTime`, but also note that `r\epoch_time` is an undefined function in PHP RQL.